# Change from {userdocs} to {commondocs}

Tags: inno-setup

My application currently installs documents and other files to two folders using lines like:

```
Source ... DestDir: {userdocs}\{#MyAppName}\Layouts
Source ... DestDir: {userappdata}\{#MyAppName}
```

Up until now I have not accommodated the need some users in classrooms have to install the software logged in as one (admin) user, but then have students use the software logged into a student account.

I have just created some code that uses [CreateInputOptionPage](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_createinputoptionpage.htm) to create a custom wizard page that asks the user whether to install to documents to the current user or all users.

How do I use the results of my new custom wizard page  to control the two Source lines above. Rather than {userdocs} and {userappdata} above, depending on the value of Page.Values[0], I want to use {commondocs} and {commonappdata}. (Is my thinking correct about using the common folders?)

Can I create some sort of runtime variable I can use in the Source lines, or an IFDEF variable?

Does iss have other built-in functionality to help me in this area?

Comment: Did you look at using separate tasks to do the two different type installs? If one task is to install for the current user and the other is to install for all users, you could configure two different `[Files]` sections (one for each task), and use the appropriate `{userdocs}` or `{commondocs}` destinations. (You also wouldn't need your custom wizard page, as the task selection would take care of the dialog.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) parameter. The `check` would refer to a function that would return a boolean value, if the return is 'true' then the entry is processed, otherwise it won't be.

```
Source ... DestDir: {userdocs}\{#MyAppName}\Layouts; Check: not IsAllUsers
Source ... DestDir: {commondocs}\{#MyAppName}\Layouts; Check: IsAllUsers

[Code]
...

function IsAllUsers: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Page.Values[0] = ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Sertac. That's exactly what I was looking for... It's nice to see an answer from a "Delphi guy!"  :-)